# How to disable all links except one on some website that is opening in the frame using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

There is a frame were a website will open i want that all links in the website is disabled except the one link suppose it to be a login link. Is it possible to disable all the links except one. So,this is what that is required.

```
<a href="" id="link_t" >link for exam</a>
        <iframe  id="frame" style=" width:100%; height: 700px;    margin:30px 0 0 0px;
          border-style: none; " src="" ></iframe>
```

on js file code is

```
var link_on_page=document.getElementById('link_t');
var divv=document.getElementById('frame');
link_on_page.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
        divv.src= "some_link"; 
    requestFullscreen(document.documentElement);
   });
```

I am calling third part website in a frame and do not want that links should open just the login link only just want to diable all links except  the one on the third party  website.

Comment: Without knowing the code you are referring to it is impossible to answer the question. Yes, it is possible to disable all the links on a website with javascript; for a short answer.

Comment: Assuming you’re framing a third party website, the answer is “you can’t do that.”

Comment: @MatthewLagerwey now i have added more details can you help me now.

Comment: @DanielBeck  why we can't.

Comment: Because CORS exists. You can’t modify the functionality of somebody else’s website, for what I would hope would be obvious reasons.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery/JavaScript: accessing contents of an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe)

Answer (score 0):

Disabling all links can except one can be accomplished like so:

```
function disableAllLinks(){
// x now contains a live collection of anchor elements
let x = document.getElementsbyTagName('a');
let j = 0;
while (x[j]){
x[j].setAttribute('href', '');
j++
}
```

Then enable the reference you want using the same idea but with

```
x = document.getElementbyId('someId');
x.setAttribute('href', 'linkgoeshere');
```

This is just a quick simple example that uses the DOM
You would then include a call to the function in the 'onclick' event function that loads the new page.

Comment: The iframe is a different `document`; this would need to run against the iframe's `.contentDocument.body` (if it were a first-party iframe.)

Comment: Sorry I assumed the link was outside of the iframe, because the code is incomplete; it looks like the link is not included in the iframe and the question is not in very clear and concise English I just gave a quick basic example on how it is done

Comment: gah, you might be right, rereading the question I really can't tell anymore